# JavaFX TextField input support for non english language

Tags: java, character-encoding, uitextfield, java-8, javafx-8

I am using javafx to build a mgmt application. in the UI I have Textfileds to insert the user data (non english characters) however when I am using the getText method, for input like "מזדה", all I am getting is "????" instead of the input itself.

Anyone has an idea how can this be fixed? I am using jdk 1.8.

Searching for similar queries didnt came up with any solution.

Comment: Post the sample text you have inserted to textfield.

Comment: if I will insert to the textfield -> מזדה Then I will get -> ????

Comment: This works fine for me. How are you checking what the result of `getText()` is?

Comment: eventually the data is pushed to the database so I can see that values are shown as "????" insted of the actual input

Comment: The problem may be with your database (or whatever you're using to view the contents of the database). Try `System.out.println(textField.getText())`, which will display the text in the console *if your console can handle non-Latin characters*. Or try `textField.getText().chars().forEach(System.out::println);`, which will display the (decimal) Unicode value for each character. For your sample text I get the values `1502`, `1494`, `1491`, `1492`.

Comment: Well i am not sure if this is the case, i also have a php file where I can add values to the database and there is no issue there, all characters are shown as they should. the collation I am using in the DB is utf8_unicode_ci. also if I am inserting values to the DB and pull them out to the application they are displayed correctly but not the other way around :-(. running your test I do get the same values but again I am not sure why they are pushed down to the DB as "????"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some additional digging I have found that the issue was that I didnt set the character encoding when registering the jdbc driver.

final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/amircar**?characterEncoding=utf8";**

hope that it will help someone